# Corresponding homogenous system derivation question

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

From Introduction to Functional Analysis with Applications by Kreszig:

> Fix $n$.
>
> Let $$\sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k^{(n)}(t_k^{(n)})^j = \frac{1}{j+1}(b^{j+1} - a^{j+1}), \text{ for $j = 0,1, \dots, n$}$$ where $\alpha_k^{(n)}$ are unknowns and $t_k^{(n)}$ are fixed elements of the interval $[a,b]$ such that $t_k^{(n)}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$.
>
> Then a unique solution exists if the corresponding homogenous system $$\sum_{k=0}^n (t_k^{(n)})^j \gamma_k= 0, \text{ where $j = 0, 1, \dots, n$}$$ has only the trivial solution $\gamma_k=0$ for all $k$ or, equally well, $\sum_{j=0}^n(t_k^{(n)})^j\gamma_j = 0, \text{ for $k = 0, \dots, n$}$

$(1.)$  How is the corresponding homogenous system formed here?  I thought $\alpha$ were the unknowns?

$(2.)$  If a solution exists in the second to last equation, why is that equivalent to a solution existing in the last equation?

Comment: The $\gamma_k$ are the unknowns. I don't understand question (2) but just in case let me make two observations: (a) The matrix of the system is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and (b) the last system in the quoted text is the same homogeneous system with the matrix transposed.

Comment: @conditionalMethod But how is the corresponding homogenous system formed?  How did the author go from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$ and what is the relationship between them?  I have edited the second question, I wrote it initially in a hurry.

Comment: The right-hand side $\frac{1}{j+1}(b^{j+1}-a^{j+1})$ gets replaced by $0$. They replaced $\alpha_k^{(n)}$ by $\gamma_k$ just to have a name $\gamma_k$ for the unknowns of the new system. There isn't much relationship between $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ since what one expects or wants is for the only solution for $\gamma$ to be zero. This is just linear algebra: The equation $ax=b$ has a solution for $x$ if and only if the equation $ay=0$ has only the solution $y=0$. Well, this is because if this is the only solution then $a\neq0$ and the inverse $a^{-1}$ exists. So one can solve ...

Comment: the first equation as $x=a^{-1}b$. The same idea is being applied for a system. That the homogeneous (and square) system has only the zero solution implies that the matrix of the system has non-zero determinant, and this implies that the matrix has an inverse. The existence of that inverse allows you to solve the in-homogeneous system.

Comment: I linked above to the Vandermonde matrix because in your equations that is the form of the matrix of those systems of equations. In particular look at the alternative condition there for when the determinant of this matrix is non-zero. The condition is that the $t_1^{(n)},t_2^{(n)},...,t_n^{(n)}$ are different.